# Fork other's package, modify it, then submit to npmjs.com. How to write package.json is appropriate?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I forked https://github.com/markedjs/marked on github, make some changes, now I want to publish it to npmjs.com. The package name changes to `@myname/marked`, how do I fill in the author information part, so that I can retain the original author info, and add my info like Name, website, email, github repo, etc?

I making some special modify for marked, only for special purpose usage. I chang the heading syntax, using `#1, #2, #3 ... #108` instead of the original `#, ##, ### ... ######` , so I must making a new package.

the original package.json:

```
{
  "name": "marked",
  "description": "A markdown parser built for speed",
  "author": "Christopher Jeffrey",
  "version": "0.8.2",
  "main": "./src/marked.js",
  "bin": "./bin/marked",
  "man": "./man/marked.1",
  "files": [
    "bin/",
    "lib/",
    "src/",
    "man/",
    "marked.min.js"
  ],
  "repository": "git://github.com/markedjs/marked.git",
  "homepage": "https://marked.js.org",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "http://github.com/markedjs/marked/issues"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  ......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your process of making changes to your favourite npm package and publishing it is incorrect.

What you would need to do is,

1. Fork the GitHub repository
2. Create a branch
3. Make your changes on the branch
4. Submit a PR from your forked repository's branch to the original repository
5. The owner/maintainer will review your PR and merge it
6. Then it's up to them to plan and release a new version which includes your changes

Comment: but I making some special modify for marked, only for special purpose usage. I chang the heading syntax, using #1, #2, #3 ... #108 instead of the original #, ##, ### ... ###### , so I must making a new package.

Comment: This is a fair question and needs to be answered appropriately.

There are many instances when a maintainer stops maintaining a package, or they refuse to merge your PR as it is out of scope, or any other possible reason. 

And it is the beauty of open source that you can fork an openly licensed repo, make your changes, and publish it for anyone else to use! This is literally the point of OSS.

Comment: @AnshNanda You are right. I didn't fully understand the context of the question. You should post an answer.